# How do I add two mysql columns together and then update the result to one of the same columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to add two columns together and then update one of those columns with the new result for each row every 5 seconds. (I know, probably not very practical in real life but it's for science!)

So this is what I figured out so far:

1. In order to make the database update happen every 5 seconds, I would either have to run a CRON job or use mySQL's event creator (I decided to go with the mySQL one) [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)
2. mySQL has something called SUM but it's really hard to understand and many of the answers are really just answers without any explanation :/
3. I would also have to run an UPDATE on the previous query.

So my table would be this:

```
kingdom(table)
____________
kingdom_id(int) | kingdom_gold(int) | kingdom_gold_rate(int)
____________
```

The idea is that kingdom_gold(int) would add kingdom_gold_rate(int) every 5 seconds. So if kingdom_gold = 0 and kingdom_gold_rate = 10; after 5 seconds kingdom_gold would be updated to 10. 5 seconds later, 20 etc...

But this would have to apply to all rows in the kingdom table. I think I understand how mysql scheduled events work but as far as adding those two columns and then updating it for every row is really beyond my understanding and I'd like to ask you all to help me learn this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be pretty simple. This ought to work:

```
UPDATE kingdom 
SET kingdom_gold = kingdom_gold + kingdom_gold_rate
```

Note that by not specifying a `WHERE` clause, the `UPDATE` will apply to all table records

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the WHERE clause. Will rate as best answer as soon as enough passes by. And for future people, this worked exactly as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The statement in your event should simply be:

```
UPDATE kingdom SET kingdom_gold = kingdom_gold + kingdom_gold_rate;
```

Comment: You guys were pretty fast! Yep, this worked really well! I was reading answers that hand INNER JOIN and SUM(etc) and I couldn't get it but this? This worked really well and I thank you all for answer it! Thanks :)